# xcopy with credentials on remote machine

Tags: batch-file, network-programming, remote-access, credentials

I am trying to access a remote server on a different domain through its IP address. In run command I entered the following

```
\\XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX\C$\Program Files\
```

I get a pop up window asking for username and password. I enter it, and accessed the path. When I try accessing the folder again it do not ask for my password. But when I restart, it does give the popup again.

Is there a way to add my credentials?? Lets say my domain\username is `MyDomain\RapsyTree`. I tried the following:

```
cmdkey /generic:TERMSRV/YYY.YY.YYY.YYY /user:YourDomain\rapsalands /pass:secretPass
```

The credentials are getting added. But I am still getting the pop up for username and password.

Actually I am trying to `xcopy` some files on this server on different domain. But I need to do it with different credentials. I am using batch files. Any pointers will be of great help. Let me know if I am not clear. I am using `Windows 7` Thanks!

Comment: why close votes......care to explain please

Comment: Why close this question ?  seems to fit the FAQ ....

Comment: I'm guessing the close votes are because this question might fit in better at [superuser](http://superuser.com/) or [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/).

Comment: If you ask the same question for C#, nobody would even think to close it. Isn't DOS a language?

Comment: Don't get offended. Many much much greater questions have been closed here by intellectuals :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You just have to map a network drive:

```
net use Z: \\XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX\C$ password /user:domain\username
```

If you want the drive to reconnect at next logon, add the option `/persistent:yes`

Comment: I don't think they really need to *map* it, though. It should be enough simply to *connect* to the shared resource. So, replacing `Z:` with `*` should work as well, if I'm not missing anything.

Comment: net use * will map a drive too ...

Comment: I removed that `Z:` path at all. And credentials are getting added and worked. But not persistent. It asks again after I logoff and login.

Comment: why not use a drive letter ? did you use /persistent:yes

Comment: yes....I used. Moreover can I delete credentials with this? +1 by the way

Comment: You are right, `*` assigns an available letter automatically. I meant removing the drive assignment, just forgot how it was done.

Comment: @rapsalands what do you mean "delete credentials" ??

Comment: if I ran the above command....then I will able to access path without using username and password. I will finish my required changes. Then I want to delete credentials so that if I try accessing the path again, it should ask for username and password. If it does not make any sense, let me know. However, I don't understand these server and remote stuff much

Comment: @rapsalands you just have to disconnect the drive : `net use Z: /D`

Answer (score 16):

You can also try this. pass the username and password as arguments. After copy it deletes the mapping & disconnects.

```
SET username=%1
SET password=%2
net use "\\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\Some Folder" %password% /user:domain\%username%
:copy
copy "\\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\Some Folder\New.txt" "D:\new.txt"
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 goto disconnect
goto end
:disconnect 
net use "\\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\Some Folder" /delete
goto end
:end
```

Comment: I think it is `copy src dst`

Answer (score 5):

try putting the IP in double quotes. It worked for me.

```
net use "\\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\Some Folder" password /user:domain\username
```

Keep me posted :)

Comment: yes it worked....I updated this in below answer, can I delete the credentials......+1

Comment: You can I mean it depends on the security policies in place at your end.

Comment: how to delete credentials....can you show a sample script

Comment: sure, 
net use "\\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\Some Folder"
copy "\\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\Some Folder\New.txt" "D:\new.txt"

Comment: Actually if you want to copy something from the desired network location and have open access to it without giving credentials.
you can directly use 

copy "\\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\Some Folder\New.txt" "D:\new.txt"  

no need to use net use command then.

Comment: I want to copy with difeerent credentials......and after copying, disconnect. Thanks for your help